# How to do default multi sort?

Tags: sorting, angular-material

this is my current code:

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'dataYear', 'dataMonth', 'population', 'sources', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'actions'];

@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

ngOnInit() {

   this.sort.sort(<MatSortable>({id: 'updated_at', start: 'desc'}));
   this.listData.sort = this.sort;
}
```

I can only make a default sorting for one column.
What if I would like to do three column ( dataYear, dataMonth, updated_at) of sorting?

Below content is the HTML component:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="listData" matSort>
<ng-container matColumnDef="id">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="hide"> Id. </mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="hide"> {{element.id}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="dataYear">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Year </mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.dataYear}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="dataMonth">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Month </mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.dataMonth}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="population">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Population </mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.population}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="sources">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Sources </mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.sources}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="created_at">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Created Time </mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.created_at}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="updated_at">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Updated Time </mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.updated_at}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
<button mat-icon-button (click)="onEdit(row)"><mat-icon>launch</mat-icon></button>
<button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="onDelete(row.id)"><mat-icon>delete_outline</mat-icon></button>
</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

Comment: can you please share your html code as well ?

Comment: @SamarthSaxena thanks for your comment first~ I've updated the component

Comment: I believe you want to sort your remaining columns, think the problem is in your onInit method there you are initializing only one column to sort . do on thing remove that area from ng on Init and try something like 

displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
for more info - https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that is supported yet, see this Github issue [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7226).

But you could just sort the data yourself, instead of relying on the Material data source to do it for you, which it can't as of now anyway (multiple field sorting that is).

Here is a quick [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-3i7ng9?file=app/app.component.ts) I threw together.

It doesn't use `matSort` at all and just sorts the data of the data source itself via an array of `Sort` objects:

```
export interface Sort {
  id: string;
  direction: 'asc' | 'desc';
}

multiSort: Sort[] = [
  { id: 'position', direction: 'desc' },
  { id: 'weight', direction: 'asc' },
  { id: 'name', direction: 'asc' }
];
```

And then the function that consumes the sort config:

```
public sort() {
  if (!this.multiSort) {
    return;
  }

  let sortedData: PeriodicElement[];
  this.multiSort.forEach(sort => {
    sortedData = this.dataSource.data
    .sort((a, b) => {
      if (sort.direction === 'asc') {
        return a[sort.id] > b[sort.id] ? 1 : -1;
      } else if (sort.direction === 'desc') {
        return a[sort.id] > b[sort.id] ? -1: 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
  });
  this.dataSource.data = sortedData;
}
```

This might not be ideal but depending on your requirements a similar solution might get you to solve this issue.

Comment: so sad...
So the only solution is that I have to adjust the Laravel back-end.
I've spend all most the whole afternoon to find out the ans :'(

Comment: 404 stackblitz link

Answer (score 3):

An Indirect way to do this is by using sortingDataAccessor function.

In your function, you can simply concatenate primary sort columns and then it will get sorted correctly.

For e.g. I want to sort due dates and then for same dates, by name.Here is how I achieved this:

```
this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
      switch (property) {
        case 'dueDate': return (item?.dueDate + item?.name);
        case 'name': return item?.name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the single sort for four times then it will come out what I want

The priority: update_at > dataYear > population > created_at

```
this.sort.sort(<MatSortable>({id: 'created_at', start: 'desc'}));
this.sort.sort(<MatSortable>({id: 'population', start: 'desc'}));
this.sort.sort(<MatSortable>({id: 'dataYear', start: 'desc'}));
this.sort.sort(<MatSortable>({id: 'updated_at', start: 'desc'}));
```